# VScode webview extension api

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview

When I read the VScode API [Supporting Remote Development and GitHub Codespaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions), I saw

```
import { getExpressServerPort } from './server'
```

I want to make my webview extension to connect to my localhost website, but I can't import `getExpressServerPort`. Where is the './server'?